# How to proceed with this exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java

[this example of code](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet262.java?view=co) generates an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3235 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:125)
    at Snippet262.main(Snippet262.java:34)
```

What does it mean please and how can I resolve it ?
Thank you

Comment: You *did* compile that piece of code. The exception was thrown when you *executed* it.

Comment: Yes exactly, but have an idea how can I proceed with this exception?

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't mis-describe your problem. It just distracts and confuses. You could always edit your question you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `swt-win32-3235.dll` to the `library_path` in your app. By default `library_path` equals to working dir (".") of your app. Or you may specify path to `library_path` in vm argument `-Djava.library.path=path`

So,
1.Check existing `swt-win32-3235.dll` in your library_path.
2. Check correct definition of `library_path` property.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I copied the swt-win32-3235.dll to the "." path and this work now. The probleme that I had is the incomplete jar library so I downloaded the library that contain this dll file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a runtime exception, that means that the code uses shared library's (using jni probably) which it cannot load.
here you have two options:

1. the shared library is not installed on you system.
2. the path to the shared lib is not  included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (on linux, not sure how it called on windows)

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.I have effectively a problem with the shared library in my system. But it's resolved now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got the error while running my application. The exception was

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception :
>   SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager.initialize(I[B[BZ)V

I fix it in eclipse as below step, Windows>Preferences>Java>Install JREs>check jre6-32 (check the appropriate versions of jre that you have install in your system).

Answer (score 0):

I found that copying the SWT dll files to the Java's JRE bin directory solved this problem.

Comment: It is better not to tamper this directory with user libraries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891114/must-i-place-all-dependent-dlls-into-the-jdks-bin-folder for other options.