# Must I place all dependent DLLs into the JDK's bin folder?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

My java application depends on a DLL, and that DLL **further** depends on `libstdc++-6.dll`.

I tried to:

- placed the `libstdc++-6.dll` in a folder
- and put the folder in the %PATH%

Then I meet the `java.lang.Unsatisfied LinkError: The specified procedure could not be found` when launching application from Eclipse.

But if I put the `libstdc++-6.dll` into the `JDK's bin folder`, say `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45_32bit\bin`. It works fine.

But I don't want to pollute the JDK folder. I remember windows will search %PATH% to locate dependent DLLs. Why can't I use the %PATH% in this issue?

### Update 1

There are 2 different %PATH% environment variables in Windows.

- User variables
- System variables

I just **accidentally** find that:

- If I put the DLL's folder to User %PATH%, it cannot be found.
- If I put the DLL's folder to System %PATH%, it works.

Why?

### Update 2

Inspired by this thread:[System versus user PATH environmental variable...winmerge works only if I add the path to the user PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270267/system-versus-user-path-environmental-variable-winmerge-works-only-if-i-add-th)

I start to wonder maybe my User %Path% is **too long**. So I moved the folder path containing my dependent DLL from the **end** of User %PATH% to the **beginning**. It works now!

At first, I conclude that one who implemented the Windows' DLL lookup algorithm has some truncation issue. And I *almost* consider it as another annoying Windows Bug.

But I wrote another Windows application which has similar DLL dependencies to confirm my guess. That application works fine! So I have to review my conclusion.

I checked my User %PATH% entry one by one, and place the folder to each possible location. And finally, I find the **root cause**.

> I have a `C:\MinGW\bin` entry in User %PATH%, which happens to contain a
>   `libstdc++-6.dll (977KB)` but unfortunately, which isn't compatible
>   with the one I need `(825KB)`. It only works if I place my folder before MinGW. So it's actually DLL collision during %PATH% resolution.

Now this issue seems resolved. But another one comes up, do I need to switch back and forth if I want to use both my DLL and the MinGW?

### Update 3

Please check the comment by @AndyThomas. He mentioned using `System.loadLibrary()` for both direct and indirect DLLs. This way, all we need to care about is the `java.library.path` property. I think that's a once-for-all solution.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with paths? The error states it cannot find the function, not library

Comment: That error message is quite misleading. Actually, I think it says my DLL depends on `libstdc++-6.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` cannot be found. Because once I put it into the JDK bin folder, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: put all DLL files you need in the same directory

Then: Load native libs - to do so you have 3 options:

1. Set VM Options while you run your app.

> -Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is
> present"

Example:

> java -Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is
> present" -jar app.jar

2. Load specific native library from within the app:

> a) Place the directory that contains the file aaa.dll directly under the Java project.
>
> b) And place this line on the top of stack trace of your app: **System.loadLibrary("aaa")**

3. Use VM options from within your app:

> System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "C:\Your Directory where Dll is
> present" );

Comment: Thanks. But your solution is for Java to locate a direct dependent DLL. My scenario is a indirect dependent DLL. That is `My Java application -> DLL -> libstdc++-6.dll`. My scenario is the second step.  I think this step should be handled by the Windows. And I thought Windows *should* use the %PATH% as the search path.

Comment: Maybe @Igo Kegel's answer could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566732/java-jni-and-dependent-libraries-on-windows

Comment: Thanks Karol. Your link is a great post to explain the concept. But I have found the root cause of my issue. See my update.

Comment: @smwikipedia - Requiring modification of the system or user %PATH% variable can be heavy-handed and a source of errors. It can be simpler and safer to install the dependent DLL alongside your application, and load it explicitly with `System.load()` or `System.loadLibrary().`

Comment: @AndyThomas  Thanks for the reminding. `System.load()` and `System.loadLibrary()` is for Java to load the direct dependent DLLs. In my scenario, it's the indirect DLLs I am having the issue, which is resolved by the Windows.

Comment: @smwikipedia - You can also use `System.load()` and `System.loadLibrary()` to load those indirect DLLs.

Comment: @AndyThomas I didn't know that could work. So if I did that, I can avoid relying on Windows to implicitly resolve indirect DLL dependency for me? And that way, all I need to care is the `java.library.path` property. Right?

Comment: @smwikipedia - Right, if you use `System.loadLibrary()`, all you need configure is the process's `java.library.path` property. If you use `System.load(String filename)`, you don't even need that.

Comment: @AndyThomas Many thanks. I just wrote a small test app. And it works like a charm. Really appreciate you telling me this. :)

Comment: @AndyThomas I am wondering if this is some kind of best practices when using native libraries with Java.

Comment: Please note that you can't change `"java.library.path"` at runtime with `System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "C:\smth" );`. It will be ignored.